# Минт тормозит из-за Хромиума с большим числом вкладок

Tags: память, linux-mint

Если открыть Хромиум с большим числом вкладок, всё начинает тормозить. Нормальная работоспособность восстанавливается только при уничтожении процессов вкладок.

Переключение между программами может занимать по полминуты, запуск новых - ещё дольше. Сворачивание всех окон - тоже. Поскольку постоянной полной загрузки процессора нет, полагаю, это всязано с использованием файла подкачки. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы основные системные программы (всё, что связано с хоткеями: Alt+Tab, Win+D, управление громкостю) не выгружались в файл подкачки? Или причина какая-то другая?

Возможно, есть другие способы решения проблемы?

```
ps axo pid,comm,rss,pmem,pcpu --sort -rss
```

```
  PID COMMAND           RSS %MEM %CPU
 2784 chromium-browse 347832  4.2 23.8
 3898 chromium-browse 302528  3.7 5.4
 3910 chromium-browse 255556  3.1 3.9
 3007 chromium-browse 246132  3.0 5.4
 2557 firefox         241204  2.9 14.0
 3925 chromium-browse 239340  2.9 4.4
 3821 chromium-browse 224332  2.7 3.5
 3093 chromium-browse 221144  2.7 3.4
 3387 chromium-browse 217460  2.6 3.2
 3601 chromium-browse 216952  2.6 4.1
 3847 chromium-browse 213476  2.6 3.6
 3052 chromium-browse 208488  2.5 16.8
 3138 chromium-browse 186372  2.3 2.1
 4794 chromium-browse 185312  2.2 3.4
 3009 chromium-browse 185212  2.2 2.6
 3070 chromium-browse 179160  2.2 2.8
 4035 chromium-browse 173048  2.1 3.4
 3291 chromium-browse 171420  2.1 2.7
 3005 chromium-browse 167076  2.0 4.6
 3651 chromium-browse 165884  2.0 2.6
 3011 chromium-browse 163760  2.0 2.9
 3214 chromium-browse 159504  1.9 2.2
 3313 chromium-browse 156400  1.9 2.6
 3370 chromium-browse 153920  1.9 2.6
 3677 chromium-browse 151452  1.8 3.5
 3795 chromium-browse 150900  1.8 3.4
 3853 chromium-browse 147060  1.8 2.1
 4457 chromium-browse 147016  1.8 2.0
 3115 chromium-browse 146744  1.8 1.8
 3190 chromium-browse 145876  1.8 1.8
 4053 chromium-browse 142608  1.7 1.7
 3553 chromium-browse 139024  1.7 2.4
 3741 chromium-browse 138420  1.7 3.1
 4147 chromium-browse 134016  1.6 2.3
 3003 chromium-browse 130128  1.6 3.9
 3382 chromium-browse 126124  1.5 2.1
 3489 chromium-browse 123520  1.5 1.5
 3512 chromium-browse 119020  1.4 1.8
 3839 chromium-browse 115236  1.4 1.7
 3054 chromium-browse 115108  1.4 0.2
 3965 chromium-browse 114780  1.4 1.7
 3778 chromium-browse 112856  1.3 1.6
 3361 chromium-browse 112200  1.3 1.9
 3429 chromium-browse 112080  1.3 1.8
 3789 chromium-browse 102536  1.2 1.4
 5118 chromium-browse 102208  1.2 1.0
 3715 chromium-browse 100156  1.2 1.2
 3171 chromium-browse 97388  1.2  1.2
 3733 chromium-browse 95408  1.1  1.9
 2888 chromium-browse 94212  1.1 33.5
 3827 chromium-browse 93940  1.1  1.1
 4340 chromium-browse 92336  1.1  0.7
 3569 chromium-browse 87244  1.0  0.6
 5207 chromium-browse 86800  1.0  1.1
 3644 chromium-browse 85632  1.0  1.5
 5385 chromium-browse 85324  1.0  1.5
 3383 chromium-browse 84848  1.0  1.5
 5326 chromium-browse 84448  1.0  1.3
 4511 chromium-browse 84440  1.0  1.2
 3505 chromium-browse 84296  1.0  1.1
 5489 chromium-browse 83724  1.0 13.6
 3607 chromium-browse 82160  1.0  1.3
 5246 chromium-browse 81216  1.0  1.1
 3160 chromium-browse 78652  0.9  1.1
 2329 cinnamon        77780  0.9  3.3
 3609 chromium-browse 75408  0.9  1.5
 5307 chromium-browse 71652  0.8  0.7
 3508 chromium-browse 69124  0.8  1.2
 3993 chromium-browse 63548  0.7  0.6
 3401 chromium-browse 40016  0.4  0.5
 1333 Xorg            37780  0.4  4.0
 2649 plugin-containe 16544  0.2  2.2
 2551 gnome-system-mo 12324  0.1  3.3
 2818 chromium-browse 12216  0.1  0.0
 2340 python          11540  0.1  0.4
 2661 gnome-terminal  10156  0.1  0.2
 2377 btsync-core      7800  0.0  0.1
 1877 cinnamon-settin  6968  0.0  0.0
 2820 chromium-browse  5768  0.0  0.0
 2385 xneur            4908  0.0  0.0
 2891 chromium-browse  4824  0.0  0.0
 2345 nemo             4648  0.0  0.0
 2346 nm-applet        4320  0.0  0.0
 2417 mintUpdate       4276  0.0  0.0
 2347 cinnamon-killer  3840  0.0  0.0
 2327 cinnamon-launch  3768  0.0  0.0
 2455 evolution-alarm  3744  0.0  0.0
 2463 applet.py        3368  0.0  0.0
 2443 cinnamon-screen  3104  0.0  0.0
 1879 gnome-keyring-d  3056  0.0  0.0
 2335 polkit-gnome-au  3000  0.0  0.0
 1742 cinnamon-sessio  2688  0.0  0.0
 5500 ps               2240  0.0  0.0
 2413 mintupdate-laun  1856  0.0  0.0
 2467 evolution-calen  1808  0.0  0.0
 1323 mdm              1784  0.0  0.0
 2349 gxneur           1700  0.0  0.1
 1810 dbus-daemon      1564  0.0  0.0
 2668 bash             1564  0.0  0.0
 1893 pulseaudio       1480  0.0  0.2
 1315 mdm              1420  0.0  0.0
 2312 colord           1360  0.0  0.0
 1263 NetworkManager   1240  0.0  0.0
 1899 upowerd          1232  0.0  0.0
 2371 gconfd-2         1232  0.0  0.0
 2528 accounts-daemon  1224  0.0  0.0
 1863 dbus-daemon      1172  0.0  0.0
 2287 gvfs-udisks2-vo  1168  0.0  0.0
 2290 udisksd          1160  0.0  0.0
 1269 polkitd          1148  0.0  0.0
 1671 console-kit-dae  1140  0.0  0.0
 2097 nmbd             1128  0.0  0.0
 2460 evolution-sourc  1124  0.0  0.0
  883 ModemManager     1092  0.0  0.0
 2389 gvfsd-trash      1068  0.0  0.0
 1866 at-spi2-registr  1064  0.0  0.0
 2524 dconf-service    1060  0.0  0.0
 2365 gvfsd-metadata   1040  0.0  0.0
 1859 at-spi-bus-laun  1036  0.0  0.0
 2121 gvfsd            1016  0.0  0.0
 2156 gvfsd-fuse        968  0.0  0.0
 1286 smbd              956  0.0  0.0
 1816 dnsmasq           936  0.0  0.0
 2299 gvfs-afc-volume   900  0.0  0.0
  681 cupsd             876  0.0  0.0
 2308 gvfs-gphoto2-vo   860  0.0  0.0
 1147 irqbalance        832  0.0  0.0
 1226 kerneloops        820  0.0  0.0
 2304 gvfs-mtp-volume   768  0.0  0.0
  774 systemd-logind    760  0.0  0.0
    1 init              756  0.0  0.0
  419 systemd-udevd     704  0.0  0.0
 1895 rtkit-daemon      660  0.0  0.0
  577 dbus-daemon       656  0.0  0.0
  402 upstart-udev-br   624  0.0  0.0
 1007 getty             624  0.0  0.0
 1531 dhclient          616  0.0  0.0
 1649 getty             616  0.0  0.0
 1026 getty             608  0.0  0.0
 1009 getty             600  0.0  0.0
 1015 getty             584  0.0  0.0
 2507 csd-printer       572  0.0  0.0
 1102 cups-browsed      568  0.0  0.0
 1017 getty             564  0.0  0.0
 1218 acpid             560  0.0  0.1
 2667 gnome-pty-helpe   560  0.0  0.0
 2095 winbindd          544  0.0  0.0
  611 upstart-file-br   536  0.0  0.0
 1330 smbd              476  0.0  0.0
  905 upstart-socket-   456  0.0  0.0
 2024 winbindd          456  0.0  0.0
 1259 cron              424  0.0  0.0
  671 rsyslogd          420  0.0  0.0
 1545 nvidia-persiste   360  0.0  0.0
 1809 dbus-launch       332  0.0  0.0
 1585 teamviewerd       272  0.0  0.2
 1302 smbd              236  0.0  0.0
  649 bluetoothd         68  0.0  0.0
 1806 ssh-agent          32  0.0  0.0
    2 kthreadd            0  0.0  0.0
    3 ksoftirqd/0         0  0.0  0.0
    4 kworker/0:0         0  0.0  0.0
    5 kworker/0:0H        0  0.0  0.0
    6 kworker/u16:0       0  0.0  0.0
    7 rcu_sched           0  0.0  0.1
    8 rcu_bh              0  0.0  0.0
    9 rcuos/0             0  0.0  0.0
   10 rcuob/0             0  0.0  0.0
   11 migration/0         0  0.0  0.0
   12 watchdog/0          0  0.0  0.0
   13 watchdog/1          0  0.0  0.0
   14 migration/1         0  0.0  0.0
   15 ksoftirqd/1         0  0.0  0.0
   17 kworker/1:0H        0  0.0  0.0
   18 rcuos/1             0  0.0  0.0
   19 rcuob/1             0  0.0  0.0
   20 watchdog/2          0  0.0  0.0
   21 migration/2         0  0.0  0.0
   22 ksoftirqd/2         0  0.0  0.0
   23 kworker/2:0         0  0.0  0.0
   24 kworker/2:0H        0  0.0  0.0
   25 rcuos/2             0  0.0  0.0
   26 rcuob/2             0  0.0  0.0
   27 watchdog/3          0  0.0  0.0
   28 migration/3         0  0.0  0.0
   29 ksoftirqd/3         0  0.0  0.0
   31 kworker/3:0H        0  0.0  0.0
   32 rcuos/3             0  0.0  0.0
   33 rcuob/3             0  0.0  0.0
   34 khelper             0  0.0  0.0
   35 kdevtmpfs           0  0.0  0.0
   36 netns               0  0.0  0.0
   37 perf                0  0.0  0.0
   38 khungtaskd          0  0.0  0.0
   39 writeback           0  0.0  0.0
   40 ksmd                0  0.0  0.0
   41 khugepaged          0  0.0  0.0
   42 crypto              0  0.0  0.0
   43 kintegrityd         0  0.0  0.0
   44 bioset              0  0.0  0.0
   45 kblockd             0  0.0  0.0
   46 ata_sff             0  0.0  0.0
   47 md                  0  0.0  0.0
   48 devfreq_wq          0  0.0  0.0
   50 kworker/2:1         0  0.0  0.0
   52 kswapd0             0  0.0  0.4
   53 fsnotify_mark       0  0.0  0.0
   54 ecryptfs-kthrea     0  0.0  0.0
   66 kthrotld            0  0.0  0.0
   68 kworker/1:1         0  0.0  0.0
   70 acpi_thermal_pm     0  0.0  0.0
   78 ipv6_addrconf       0  0.0  0.0
   79 kworker/1:2         0  0.0  0.0
   98 deferwq             0  0.0  0.0
   99 charger_manager     0  0.0  0.0
  172 scsi_eh_0           0  0.0  0.0
  173 scsi_tmf_0          0  0.0  0.0
  174 scsi_eh_1           0  0.0  0.0
  175 scsi_tmf_1          0  0.0  0.0
  176 scsi_eh_2           0  0.0  0.0
  177 scsi_tmf_2          0  0.0  0.0
  178 scsi_eh_3           0  0.0  0.0
  179 scsi_tmf_3          0  0.0  0.0
  180 scsi_eh_4           0  0.0  0.0
  181 scsi_tmf_4          0  0.0  0.0
  182 scsi_eh_5           0  0.0  0.0
  183 scsi_tmf_5          0  0.0  0.0
  186 kworker/u16:5       0  0.0  0.0
  277 jbd2/sdb2-8         0  0.0  0.0
  278 ext4-rsv-conver     0  0.0  0.0
  406 kworker/0:1H        0  0.0  0.0
  486 edac-poller         0  0.0  0.0
  490 irq/29-mei_me       0  0.0  0.0
  557 kworker/1:1H        0  0.0  0.0
  559 hd-audio1           0  0.0  0.0
  560 hd-audio0           0  0.0  0.0
  609 kvm-irqfd-clean     0  0.0  0.0
  631 kmpathd             0  0.0  0.0
  632 kmpath_handlerd     0  0.0  0.0
  661 krfcommd            0  0.0  0.0
 1359 kworker/2:1H        0  0.0  0.0
 1537 iprt-VBoxWQueue     0  0.0  0.0
 1538 iprt-VBoxTscThr     0  0.0  0.0
 1668 kauditd             0  0.0  0.0
 2416 sh                  0  0.0  0.0
 2660 kworker/3:1H        0  0.0  0.0
 2706 kworker/0:2         0  0.0  0.0
 2980 kworker/3:6         0  0.0  0.0
 2981 kworker/3:7         0  0.0  0.0
 3958 kworker/u16:1       0  0.0  0.0
```

(UPD) Всё-таки удалось сделать скриншот с Системного монитора (данные могут отличаться от вывода выше и следующего скрина):

[image: Скриншот из другой сессии]

И скриншот Системного монитора, который удалось сделать только после прибивания хромиумов (но ступеньку с падением потребления памяти видно):

[image: Системный монитор после прибивания хромиумных вкладок]

Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 x64
Chromium 51.0.2704.79

Comment: у меня Минт тоже тормозил , я его сменил на Ubuntu и вообще нету проблем ни с чем

Comment: @Geyan, у меня ничего не тормозит, если Хромиум с таким числом вкладок не запускать. Как видишь, в списке 71 процесс `chromium-browser` с суммарным потреблением памяти около 114% и 228% процессора (просуммировал по списку в вопросе). Кстати, а для процессора лимит 400% (каждое ядро по 100%) или как?

Comment: я на столько глубоко в Линь не погружался , у меня стоит Убунта и цены нету ей

Comment: @Geyan, если откроешь хромикм с примерно 300 вкладками, то тормозить всё равно не будет? А оперативки 8 или больше?

Comment: озу 16 ггб , я столько не открываю - максимум 34 открывал

Comment: @Geyan, с 34 у меня проблем тоже не было. Вроде даже с сотней нормально. И 16 гигов - это полно - у меня даже все 300 столько не используют :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подумайте, как работает операционная система: у нее есть виртуальная память (физическая + swap раздел - в линуксе нет 'файла подкачки'),  чтобы обеспечить многозадачность, система переключается между всеми открытыми приложениями.

допустим, у вас хром сжирает 9 гигов, а вся остальная система - 4 гига.

а у вас 12 гигов.

вы открываете кучу вкладок, съедаете 9 гигов, дальше начинается что? приблизительно: система начинает сбрасывать на диск неиспользуемые и неизмененные страницы, все начинает тормозить.

в это время вы переключаетесь на контроль звука или какой-то процесс убунты поднимается проверить свое состояние, поскольку он сброшен на диск,  все начинает тормозить. потом система переключается в хром, поскольку в хроме тоже идет своя движуха и он не спит, и начинает подкачивать его страницы с диска.

нет, никак нельзя. разве что черной магией. поставьте себе больше памяти. и почитайте про архитектуру компьютера

p.s. не забывайте, что в Linux еще существует целая прослойка между пользовательским вводом/выводом  - и это [Xorg](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). Клиент/серверная модель не очень подходит для локального компьютера, хотя для сетевых приложений/терминалов прошлых лет подходила отлично - Попробуйте wayland (если получится) или что-нибудь такое. В Windows таких тяжелых посредников просто нет, GUI/ввод там гораздо сильнее интегрирован с ядром и драйверами.

Может вам проще хром оптимизировать, есть расширения, которые вкладки закрывают/усыпляют, что-нибудь вроде `The Great Suspender`

Comment: Вот замечательное описание [модели памяти Windows](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6784461#p6784461). Если есть что-то подобное про линукс, буду рад почитать. Дальше. В винде проблем при таком числе вкладок гораздо меньше. Да, программы тоже тормозят. Но всякие Alt+Tab работают куда адекватнее. Насколько я понимаю, это из-за того, что некоторое страницы помечены невыгружаемыми и система способна обработать некоторые вещи без загрузки страниц из файла подкачки. Почему в линуксе не так же? Можно ли сделать, чтобы было так же? Выставить какие-то параметры процессам? Приоритет? Ещё что-то?

Comment: можно выставить оболочке и оконному менеджеру приоритет повыше. не знаю, насколько это поможет. в целом-то советы по оптимизации - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/maximizing_performance но не настолько детальные. зачем вам вообще столько вкладок хрома? cpulimit-ом можете ограничить потребление цпу процессом. но в целом тормоза не уйдут, думаю. кроме того, откуда мы знаем, может у вас драйвер видео плохо работает->gui еще больше тормозит

Comment: Просто они у меня как-то накапливаются... В винде сильные проблемы начинаются после 1000 вкладок, а в минте почему-то уже после 300. Хотя, в винде гугловский хром, а тут-то хромиум - может это тоже как-то влияет... Статью сейчас прочитаю.

Comment: А можно по-подробнее про Xorg?

Comment: обновил ответ слегка.

Comment: При этот как раз Windows (по крайней мере семёрка и десятка) не тормозит в случае отжирания памяти процессом.

Comment: @VladD вот я уверен, что можно найти адовое решение для конкретного случая, но не сталкивался с таким экстремальным примером и никогда не искал подобных вещей. И да, семерка тоже вполне могла тормозить, если жрать хорошенько ресурсы (давно не использовал, но помню)

Comment: @strangeqargo: У меня всё в порядке с ней было. Сейчас десятка, летает.

Comment: @VladD, процессов много, не один. Я так когда-то делал прогу, вешающую систему намертво - просто запустить себя 5 раз и завершиться (чтобы разорвать дерево процессов) - всё шикарно висло. Семёрка где-то на 1000 вкладок начинает работать очень плохо. Около 500 - вполне адекватно, хотя приложения тормозят, а загрузка процессора держится на более чем 50%. И такое ощущение, что она постепенно вкладки хрома отправляет в подкачку, а минт напротив их держит в оперативной памяти, как последние запустившиеся процессы.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну это да, но общих проблем не вызывало никогда. У линукса есть старая болячка недесктопной ОС: заметное торможение UI при интенсивных файловых операциях.

Comment: А как насчёт параметра `vm.swappiness`? // + @VladD

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я не в курсе, никогда не пытался тонко настроить Линукс :-(

Comment: с vm.swappiness если что, поосторожней будьте, можно легко свалиться (неопасно, просто можно не загрузиться после применения настроек)

Comment: можно попробовать поменять диспетчер процессов или попробовать что-нибудь вроде https://liquorix.net/ - и похожие альтернативы (zen kernel). ядро с настройками заточенными под десктопы

Comment: А минт разве не под десктоп заточен?

Comment: я думаю, он заточен "менее экстремально" чем кастомное ядро, все-таки он наследник убунты, убунта - дебиана, и они все более-менее десктопные (ну кроме сервер-редакций). Минт просто с добавками драйверов, сменой дефолтов, другим десктопом.